Foreign movie with a boiling pan bath scene
I saw a movie perhaps 5 or 10 years ago that I remember to be really good, but I do not remember its title any more. 
The only thing I remember about it is that it had a funny scene in which 2 friends were bathing each one inside a floor mounted restaurant boiling pan.
It was definitely not an American movie and I think it was not in any language I would recognize (like english, german, russian, spanish, french, italian or portuguese). 
The movie took place mostly in an apartment complex and they were poor guys. I don`t remember much more.
It was most likely in Dutch/Flemish or some Scandinavian language, but maybe it was English or Irish with a strong accent that was giving me a hard time. 
Following the guidelines: European movie, not sure what language, color moving picture, from 1980-2010 (my best guess would be like 1999?), maybe drama/comedy.
I know this is not much information, hope you can help me.

Maybe it helps to know that this was a good movie. Not a 3.6 IMBd rated, painful to watch film, but something people might enjoy. The only peculiar aspect of it is not being made in the US or Canada, as far as I can remember.

Do you remember at least how old were these guys and what they looked like?

20-30 year olds? or maybe older immigrants, I really don't remember well

Could it bePippi Longstockings (Pippi Långstrump in Swedish)?
There is this scene: 


The first clip is from the original movie, though Dutch dubbed. It originates from Sweden. The second is a (presumably American) remake.
From what I can tell (see IMDB), this particular first movie of the series is simply called 'Pippi Långstrump' just like the main character.

Unfortunately not. I know Pippi from children's books and would have made the assumption really fast if it were the case.
The movie I am talking about is with adults in the beginning of their lives
